# Is this true, the floor acts like one giant amplifier?

Tags: acoustics

It sound like the tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/dPzbuEunSLk?t=628) (a video link with a time stamp)

> soundproofing as i say it's all about
>   density. it's also about transmission of
>   sound through solid surfaces. so any two
>   surfaces that touch each other sound
>   will very easily transfer between one
>   object that's making a racket through another object that can almost amplify
>   the sound.
>   so floors are a big problem with drum
>   kits, because the floor acts like one
>   giant amplifier ...

Is this true, the floor acts like one giant amplifier? If yes, which acoustics rule is working?

Comment: Metaphorically or literally?

Comment: FWIW, it said, _almost_ amplify. That's because in order to truly amplify a sound, one must add energy to the sound. A _[sound board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_board_(music))_ (or a wooden floor) does not add any energy to the vibrations. All it does is, it provides a large surface from which the acoustic energy can be coupled into the air.

Answer (score 2):

Solids and fluids sometimes conwey sound waves far better than air. F.e. whales are said to communicate over 4000km or more. Even the loudest human voices would not be transmitted beyond a few hundred meters via air.

A floor without any soundproofing may also convey the waves from one room to the other. Even if no voices may be transmitted via air -> wall/floor -> air to an adjacent room, a needle falling on a solid floor could be heard.

F.e. parquet floors with tight fitting elements and without separating soft layers can act like a drum transferring any mechanically induced noise - walking/tapping/stumping inhabitants or pets, falling things, expanding pipes etc.  - in neighbouring rooms, even if voices can not be heard.
Compared to air it looks like amplification, but it is just a better less lossy transfer of sound waves.